# Anything like template references in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a form whose layout is entirely data driven.

Example data source:

```
{
    title : "Form Test",
    fields : [{
            name : "FieldA",
            type : "string",
            value : "initial value"
        }, {
            name : "FieldB",
            type : "selection",
            options : ["1", "2", "3"],
            value : "2"
        }, {
            name : "FieldC",
            type : "struct",
            value :
            [{
                    name : "FieldC1",
                    type : "string",
                    value : "initial value"
                }, {
                    name : "FieldC2",
                    type : "string",
                    value : "initial value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I think can use ng-repeat and ng-switch to choose the form element depending on the 'type', however I get stuck when it comes to doing this recursively when I get to 'FieldC'.

```
<span ng-switch on="field.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="string">STRING: {{field.value}}</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="selection">SELECTION: {{field.value}}</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="struct">STRUCT: ????</div>
    <div ng-switch-default>DEFAULT:{{field.value}}</div>
</span>
```

Essentially I want a way that when I encounter a "struct" it recursively applies the ng-switch to the struct fields?  Is there any way to "reference" the template so it can be used in multiple places on the same page?  The support for template "partials" seems to need to be coordinated server-side via routes which seems like overkill here.  Is this something where I need to start digging into creating my own directives?

**EDIT** I just stumbled across [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/) that looks like it has a decent chance of doing what I want (I have yet to properly test it), is that in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to build a directive that takes this kind of data and builds the form from it.

The way to treat the recursion is to treat every level, including the top level, as another struct.  I built a version here: http://jsfiddle.net/U5Kyp/9/

Make sure you read the directive guide in the docs so you understand what's happening: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I tried a couple of approaches, but in the end this was the only one that didn't have other problems.

Comment: Surprisingly simple, very nice!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an update of accepted answer for angular.js 1.0.1 There were a few non-compatible changes in stable version:

1. ng-app is now required directive
2. scope syntax and semantics were changed

http://jsfiddle.net/9qAfM/1/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a bad case of the [inner platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). Quoting wikipedia: "tendency of software architects to create a system so customizable as to become a replica, and often a poor replica, of the software development platform they are using".

AngularJS already has a powerful mechanism for traversing a tree of objects and building a stack of scopes and controllers out of it. You could argue that it is **exactly what AngularJS IS**.

If you are forced to build forms out of such abominable JSON, I think the easiest way is to turn them into HTML (by means of a simple template language of any kind, server side or client side) and then using  the $compile service to turn them into an angularjs application.